# URP Lit Shader on 2D sprite delayed reaction to directional light - Unity 2021.3.11f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite, lightning, urp

So I have a HD2D Setup in Unity, meaning a 3D world containing 2D sprites (billboards). I am using URP and created a Lit Shader with the following configuration:
[image]

This Shader is attached to a material and this material is attached to my sprite. My problem is, when I rotate the global directional light, the sprite with this shader attached has sort of a delay in adjusting its darkness to the global light (in the video, the environment is bright (morning) but the sprite is still very dark in color (see next picture) and vice versa). This behavior can be seen in the video I uplaoded here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAm71ftfy2Y

Desired outcome:
The sprite gets darker as the sun fades (similar to the white Quad that can be seen in the video scene).

[image]

Does anyone have an idea which setting I need to tweak here? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason, URP Pipeline was not set under Edit-->ProjectSettings-->Graphics. Once set, I was able to set [X] Will be affected by shadows in shader graph. This solved the problem